# Check array length in object javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some object like this

```
    const array = 
    {
      "entities": [
        {
          "annexes": [
            {
              "buildingUniqueIds": []
            },
            {
              "buildingUniqueIds": []
            },
            {
              "buildingUniqueIds": []
            },
          ],
          "buildingUniqueIds": []
        }
      ]
}
```

I need to check if any of those array is empty to return true, is this possible to do in one iteration, here is what I have tried for now, but **some** does not check array length it always return true even if array is empty :(

```
  get haveBuildingUniqueIds(): boolean {
    const condition1 = this.array.entities.some(x => x.annexes.some(y => y.buildingUniqueIds.some));
    const condition2 = this.array.entities.some(x => x.buildingUniqueIds.some);
    return condition1 && condition2;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`some` is the right method to use, but it's a *method*, not a flag, so your innermost `.some(y => y.buildingUniqueIds.some)` will always return `true`, because a method is a truthy value.

Instead, check `length`:

```
const hasEmpties = array.entities.some(({annexes, buildingUniqueIds}) =>
    buildingUniqueIds.length === 0 ||
    annexes.some(({buildingUniqueIds}) => buildingUniqueIds.length === 0)
);
```

Live Example:

```js
function check(label, array) {
    const hasEmpties = array.entities.some(({annexes, buildingUniqueIds}) =>
        buildingUniqueIds.length === 0 ||
        annexes.some(({buildingUniqueIds}) => buildingUniqueIds.length === 0)
    );
    console.log(label, "=>", hasEmpties);
}

check("all empty", {
    "entities": [
        {
            "annexes": [
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": []
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": []
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": []
                },
            ],
            "buildingUniqueIds": []
        }
    ]
});

check("none empty", {
    "entities": [
        {
            "annexes": [
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
            ],
            "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
        }
    ]
});

check("entities.buildingUniqueIds empty", {
    "entities": [
        {
            "annexes": [
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
            ],
            "buildingUniqueIds": []
        }
    ]
});

check("entities.annexes.buildingUniqueIds[1] empty", {
    "entities": [
        {
            "annexes": [
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": []
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
            ],
            "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
        }
    ]
});
```

Side note: If you like, you can use `!buildingUniqueIds.length` rather than `buildingUniqueIds.length === 0`.

Or without destructuring if you prefer:

```
const hasEmpties = array.entities.some(entity =>
    entity.buildingUniqueIds.length === 0 ||
    entity.annexes.some(annex => annex.buildingUniqueIds.length === 0)
);
```

Live Example:

```js
function check(label, array) {
    const hasEmpties = array.entities.some(entity =>
        entity.buildingUniqueIds.length === 0 ||
        entity.annexes.some(annex => annex.buildingUniqueIds.length === 0)
    );
    console.log(label, "=>", hasEmpties);
}

check("all empty", {
    "entities": [
        {
            "annexes": [
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": []
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": []
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": []
                },
            ],
            "buildingUniqueIds": []
        }
    ]
});

check("none empty", {
    "entities": [
        {
            "annexes": [
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
            ],
            "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
        }
    ]
});

check("entities.buildingUniqueIds empty", {
    "entities": [
        {
            "annexes": [
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
            ],
            "buildingUniqueIds": []
        }
    ]
});

check("entities.annexes.buildingUniqueIds[1] empty", {
    "entities": [
        {
            "annexes": [
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": []
                },
                {
                    "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
                },
            ],
            "buildingUniqueIds": [{}]
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: @MiomirDancevic - Sorry, missed that that wasn't just another entry in `annexes`, but it's an easy fix. I've updated the answer.

Comment: 'buildingUniqueIds' is already declared in the upper scope.

Comment: @MiomirDancevic - That's okay, it just gets shadowed. But you don't have to use destructuring if you don't want to.

Comment: Can you please help me sonar cloud does not allow that

Comment: @MiomirDancevic - I've updated the answer, but I do recommend reading up on parameter destructuring so you can do it yourself next time.